# Blocking user by IP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to do an block system using IP, since my old one is failing (not actually failing, take a look on this link for more informations [Stackoverflow - Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593969/issue-with-cookies-php)

Well, i know how to get the user IP and of course store it on the database.
My doubt is how can i specify the time to expire and how can i delete it in the database after the time expired, of course automatically. For example...

- User do a comment
- Stores the user IP for 30 seconds in the database
- User cannot comment again until expire the 30 seconds
- Delete automatically the IP after the expire time from the database
- User now able to comment again

Sorry for my english. If something is not clear, please tell me and i will explain better.

@EDIT

Well, resuming all of it, my doubt is:

- How can i do on the database (fields and the data on the fields) the time to expire (for example, 30 seconds).
- How can i do to delete the row that is already expired.

Comment: It's not clear where exactly is your problem? What are you struggling with?

Comment: Why not just, when a user tries to comment, check the timestamp of the last comment and, if younger than 30 seconds, prevent the user from commenting?

Comment: You could possibly use a session variable instead of writing to a DB for 30 seconds. Of course, if the user closes his browser and restarts it again, he'd be able to comment, but I think probably it would take more than 30 seconds to log in, find the page, and type the comment.

Comment: @GarethL Unless they're a spambot. Which is why other solutions are probably better. =)

Comment: @J.Steen - yes, you are right. point taken.

Comment: For now, the session solution would satisfy me, since i would not need to write on the database.

Comment: Why do you bother to delete at all? For memory reasons? Even if the whole Internet wrote a comment on your site and you would have ALL ipv4 addresses in your DB, this would be about 20GB.

Comment: @Francois Bourgeois cause people can do more than one comment, of course. Imagine i store comments and also the IP from their comments in another table? It's waste of memory.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL

```
INSERT INTO `_table` (`ip_address`, `reason`, `expire`) VALUES ('10.10.10.10', 'I don\'t like what you did.', '1362268800');
```

That record should be in a database table and I've set it to expire on 31st February.

```
//PHP Checking code.
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `reason` FROM `_table` WHERE `ip_address` = '".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."' AND `expire` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() LIMIT 1");

if (mysql_num_rows($query)){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo $row["reason"];
} //end if.
```

The above actively checks to see if the viewers IP address is found and would then echo the reason.

Comment: I've given you this, in it's most basic form so that you can read it, understand, and develop it yourself. If you're bothered about bots, I'd suggest looking at the $_SERVER["USER_AGENT"]; variable because most bots have their own distinct name on them.

Comment: Hi @Richard Dickinson. I would like to know how can i for example add more 30 seconds from the time. For example, now is 11:25:00am and i want to add +30 seconds. So, i will expire at 11:25:30am. Also, after expired, how to delete automatically? Is this "USER_AGENT"?

Comment: Firstly, don't delete entries from your database, it becomes difficult to understand a users experience if you're always deleting things, keep them in there and when your database slows down, archive off sections. - Secondly, the query I made, will only pull results from the future, so create an index on the `expire` column. Lastly, look up http://www.php.net/mktime - mktime(Hour, Minute, Second, Month, Day, Year); - This is the best way to create a timestamp for  the future, or use time()+30